# How can I uninstall Firefox OS?

Tags: uninstallation, operating-system

I was handed a phone from my friend who installed Firefox OS over Android, but now wants Android back. I know roughly how to flash ROMs, but am not sure how to go into download mode or equivalent in Firefox OS. Any help would be appreciated.

The model of the phone is a ZTE Kis. If I can supply any more information just ask!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Firefox OS which is outside the scope of this site.

Comment: Since the OP is trying to put stock Android back on what was originally an Android phone I think this question is okay here.

Comment: If you have any suggestions of where else to put it I would happily try there as well.

Comment: Hmmm... ok, concise summary, get the stock firmware (*read* Android) from Zte's website, un-raring/unzipping the archive, then go into boot-loader mode and use `fastboot` to flash the stock firmware on it (*read* the image after extraction from the rar/zip)

Answer (score 3):

Steps to Access *Download Mode* on ZTE Kis 3 Max

1. Turn off the device
2. Remove the memory card from the device
3. Press and hold <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> key + <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> key simultaneously
4. Press and hold <kbd>Power</kbd> key until the device completely freezes.

You can flash a ROM as usual after that. The stock ROM for your phone can be downloaded [here.](http://www.modaco.com/forums/topic/373101-zte-kis-3-zte-open-c-stock-roms/)

[Source](http://www.recovery-mode.com/android/zte-kis-3-max.html)

Comment: I have tried for some time now to get into download move with no success. I believe the phone itself is now stuck in a boot loop, as it will never get past the Firefox OS loading screen. Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to try [this](https://sites.google.com/site/zteopenfirmware/download-mode) out. (Note that that is **NOT** for your exact phone model. Read the whole thing first. It may or may not work with your model.) In case that doesn't work, you could try browsing/asking a question on [r/FirefoxOS](https://www.reddit.com/r/FirefoxOS).

Answer (score -1):

Go to the Play Store and download and install a launcher e.g. Google Now Launcher. When you open the launcher it will give you options to select an interface you wish to use. Select a new one and your phone will exit the Firefox OS Launcher. Then if you'd like to permanently delete the Firefox OS Launcher go to Settings/Personal/Home and you'll find your launchers there. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The Firefox OS is not a simple application - it's the whole Operating System. There is currently no android running on this device so you might want to edit your answer to actually adress this topic

Comment: Read the question again. You'll notice that it is in fact a Firefox launcher running over android. I'm speaking from experience with the "OS". Search for it and try it then you'll understand.

Comment: You can read about it here: http://www.xda-developers.com/overlay-firefox-os-on-your-android-device/

Comment: the article is from June 11, 2015. I question if the app was already available on March 2014 - the date the question was asked. The OP doesn't mention a laucher anywhere but speaks of a custom rom (the firefox OS one). So he wants to roll back to his stock rom which AJDFHLOef describes perfectly.

Comment: As stated by @Oogpister, the device is not just running a launcher, but a whole OS. I have no access to Google Play through the device.